# unix: double quote and $ is removing exactly one digit

Tags: shell, posix, double-quotes

In the Posix Standard there are some Definitions for the behavior of characters inside of Double Quotes, e.g. "".

There are different expansions that are taking place on such characters. But one behavior I'm unable to find a representation/description of in the standard/internet is this:

```
// Longest possible Name of a Variable, : is not a valid character in the name of a variable
~>echo "$aa:"
:

// The first character of name is not a digit
~>4=test
error 4=test is not a directory (or a similar error message)

// So this can't fall under parameter expansion?
~>echo "$4a:"
a:

// Hu?
~>echo "$44a:"
4a:
```

Excerpts of the possible standard sections:

> 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion
>
> If the parameter name or symbol is not enclosed in braces, the expansion shall use the longest valid name (see the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 3.230, Name), whether or not the symbol represented by that name exists.
>
> 3.230 Name
>
> In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set. The first character of a name is not a digit.

Enviroment is a Fedora 19 64-bit standard terminal without any modifications.

Thanks in advance for clarification what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the section on [positional parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html):

> 2.5.1 Positional Parameters
>
> A positional parameter is a parameter denoted by the decimal value
>   represented by one or more digits, other than the single digit 0. The
>   digits denoting the positional parameters shall always be interpreted
>   as a decimal value, even if there is a leading zero. When a positional
>   parameter with more than one digit is specified, the application shall
>   enclose the digits in braces (see Parameter Expansion). Positional
>   parameters are initially assigned when the shell is invoked (see sh),
>   temporarily replaced when a shell function is invoked (see Function
>   Definition Command), and can be reassigned with the set special
>   built-in command.

When you say:

```
echo "$4a:"
```

the shell attempts to expand a positional parameter, namely `$4` and concatenates `a:` with the expansion of the parameter.

Similarly, for

```
echo "$44a:"
```

`4a:` is concatenated to the expansion of `$4`.

---

Note that if you actually wanted to refer to a positional parameter `$44`, you'd need to say `${44}` else the shell would concatenate `4` to the expansion of `$4`.